# strcat for dynamic char pointers

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I need to write a strcat in C. I tried below things:

```
 char * c_strcat( char * str1, const char * str2)
 {

      char * ret = (char *) malloc(1 + strlen(str1)+ strlen(str2) );

     if(ret!=NULL)
     {
         strcpy(ret, str1);
         strcat(ret, str2);

     if(str1 !=NULL) free str1; // If I comment this everything will be fine 
       return ret;
     }

     return NULL;
 }     


 int main()
 {

 char * first = "Testone";
 char *second = "appendedfromhere";

 first = c_strcat(first,second);
 if(second !=NULL) free(second);

// I want to store the result in the same variable 

 }
```

It crashed whenever I free the str1 memory in the c_strcat function. If I don't free then the memory allocated for the first will be leaked (if I understood properly).

How to store returned value to same variable (first)?

Comment: [Do NOT cast the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Comment: Better avoid freeing of externally allocated memory inside the function. Free on the level where you allocated the memory. However, first and second must not be freed at all as mentioned in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From section *7.20.3.2 The free function* of the C99 standard:

> The `free` function causes the space pointed to by `ptr` to be deallocated, that is, made
>   available for further allocation. If `ptr` is a null pointer, no action occurs. **Otherwise, if
>   the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by the `calloc`, `malloc`, or
>   `realloc` function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`,
>   the behavior is undefined.**

And `str1` (aka `first`) was *not* allocated by one of the three dynamic memory allocating functions, causing the crash. Same for `second` also.

> if don't free then the memory allocated for the `first` will be leaked(if am understood properly).

Memory will be leaked if `malloc()`, `realloc()` or `calloc()` is used and the memory is not `free()`d at a later point. As the string literal `"Testone"` is not dynamically allocated it must not be freed.

Note that the pointer `NULL` check prior to invoking `free()` is unrequired as `free()`, as described above, does nothing if the pointer argument is `NULL`.

---

[Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 1):

`"Testone"` & `"appendedfromhere"` are string literals, constants. They weren't allocated using `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()`, so you cannot `free` them.

Comment: "They are in RO .data section not on the heap" may or may not be true. It's worthless to start a speculation about implementation details. They were not allocated using `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()`, so you can't `free()` them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the results to str1 (like strcat does) the memory needed for the concatenated string must be allocated externally. I.e. str1 (first) must be large enough to hold first + second., e.g. by:

```
char first[100] = "Testone";
```

Than inside your c_strcat you do not allocate nor free any memory but just write str2 at the end ('\0') into str1.